# Keeping OpenGL object a fixed size on screen

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to keep a simple cube a fixed size on screen no matter how far it translates into the scene (slides along the z axis).

I know that using an orthogonal projection, I could draw an object at fixed size, but I'm not interested in just having it look right. I need to read out the x and z coordinates (in world space) at any given time.

So the further along the -z axis the cube translates, the larger are its x and z values getting in order for the cube to still be a defined pixel size on screen (let's say the cube should be 50x50x50 pixel).

I'm not sure how to begin tackling this, any suggestions?

Comment: _but I'm not interested in just having it look right._ can you explain?

Comment: I need the cube to grow in object space as it moves along the -z axis so that it maintains a width of 50 pixel on screen. The cube in worldspace would be smaller the closer it is to the near plane, and larger the closer it gets to the far plane. Onscreen however, the width should stay 50pixel.

Comment: @Lngly: This might come as a surprise to you, but in OpenGL there is no such thing as a scene. OpenGL is a pure drawing API, processing one point, line or triangle at a time. And the only thing that matters is: *How does it look on the screen.* So as far as OpenGL is concerned, if it *looks* right it's job is done. Any scene management above that is your burden.

Comment: Well then my question would be geared towards how to get that particular scene management going. My guess is that I can use the Projection matrix to solve my problem, I just haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: @Lngly: Could you post some of your rendering code here for us to look at? I think I may have a solution for you but I will need to see your code to give you more explicit instructions. In the meanwhile, here's what I think you will need to do. Starting with your bounding box (50x50 pixels) in screen space, multiply the co-ordinates by the **inverse** of your transformation matrix. This process will transform the co-ordinates into object space. You will then need to scale your cube so that it fits within the bounding box.